# Prove that the ring is Artinian and find a composition series of ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, artinian

I came across the following problem

Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[t^2,t^3]/(t^4)$. The ring $k[t^2,t^3]$ is defined as the set $\{f(t^2,t^3)|f \in k[x,y]\}$ with the obvious ring structure.

1. prove that the ring R is Artinian
2. find ideals $A_0, \dots , A_n \unlhd R$ such that $$R=A_0 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq A_n$$ with each $A_i/A_{i+1}$ be a simple $R$ module.

**for the first part**, I know that in a short exact sequence of R-modules, the middle R-module is Artinian iff the two others are.

I thing that $R \simeq k[x,y,z]/(x-z^2, y-z^3, z^4)$ but I don't now how is this helpful.

**for the second part** I don't have a single clew how to proceed.

Any hints, useful remarks or theorems that may help are appreciated.

Comment: For $1$, notice that $R$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier So, I have to find a $k$ - basis of $R$? I think this easy, if I describe the form of elements of $R$.

Provided that, a descending chain of ideals, it is a descending chain of vector spaces so it terminates, since dimension of vector spaces has minimum.   

For the second part, I think that, provided a bases of $R$, the chain of ideals are a chain of subspaces such that their dimension is increasing by 1 at every step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we denote by $t^n$ the class of $t^n$ in $R$, the elements of $R$ can be written as $a_0+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+a_5t^5$, with $a_i\in{k}$, and a composition series is $0\subset(t^5)\subset(t^2)\subset(t^2,t^3)$.

Observe that $R$ is not a principal ideal ring; indeed the ideal $(t^2,t^3)$ is not principal.

Otherwise, the ring $k[x,y,z]/(x-z^2,y-z^3,z^4)\cong{k(z)/(z^4)}$ is a principal ideal ring; so it is not isomorphic to $R$.

Comment: isn't $t^5 = 0 \mod (t^4) $? Thanks, for noticing the wrong claim about isomorphic rings

Comment: No, we have $t^5=t\cdot{t^4}$, but $t\notin{k[t^2,t^3]/(t^4)}$. The elements of $k[t^2,t^3]$ are $a_0+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+a_4t^4+\cdots$, and the elements of $(t^4)$ are $a_4t^4+a_6t^6+a_7t^7+\cdots$.

Comment: ok, I see now! So $R$ is a 4 dimensional $k$ vector space? do you happen to know any way to find the dimension without computing the base? can we express $R$ as a quotient of polyonimal ring over $k$?

Comment: Since $R$ is not a principal ideal ring, it is never a quotient of a polynomial ring. To compute the $k$-dimension, in a more general situation,  you may use numerical semigroups.

Comment: is this "Since  is not a principal ideal ring, it is never a quotient of a polynomial ring." a fact? every ideal of $k[x,\dots,y]/A$ is principal? I thought that $R \simeq k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2,x^2)$

Comment: In my last comment we are talking about the polynomial ring $k[t]$, which is a principal ideal domain, so every quotient of this polynomial ring is a principal ideal ring. 

In your example, the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ is not a principal ideal domain and neither is the ring $R\cong{k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2,x^2)}={k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)}$, since the ideal $(x,y)/(x^2,y^2)$ is not principal.

Comment: yeah! of course we were talking about $k[t]$.. sorry, for the confusion.. thanks, for your patience